# Ribbon instances per Document

Tags: ms-office, vsto, ribbon

I am using  VSTO 3.0 and the ribbon designer gives me a ribbon that is apparently shared across documents.

So if I have Document specific state( number of XML marked up tags say) that needs to show up in the ribbon( or a toggle button ) then all documents seem to share the ribbon instance

How can I fix this 
TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hook into an appropriate event (such as when the active document is changed) within the document model, and in that event invalidate the appropriate ribbon button (you'll need the id of the element from the original Ribbon xml you load).

Then, when the refresh state callback for that button occurs, you can update the caption/image/enabled as required.

Comment: I know it's been dead for 6 years, but I'm currently going through this trauma.
Where do you mean when you refer to 'within the document model'?

Comment: If memory serves (it has been a while) there are events on the Application object that you can register with to be notified when the active document changes. These give you an opportunity to invalidate the ribbon buttons and thus trigger an update to reflect the appropriate state for the new active document.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Application.DocumentChange event or Application.WindowActivate event.

The first is fired then you change the current active document, but in the arguments there's no information about that document, so it's difficult to work with because you'll have to figure that out.

The latter is similar and it's fired every time you change of window but in this case it passes the current active document as an argument, so it's easier to change the ribbon if you need to check the value of any document property. That worked for me.